# An example of set which is not Souslin set

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

**DEFINITION**

Let $X$ be a topological space. A set $B \subseteq X$ is called Souslin set if there is a family of closed sets $\{F_s|s \in \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}} \}$ in $X$ such that $$B=\bigcup_{\sigma \in \mathbb{N^N}} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{\sigma\upharpoonright n}$$

**Question**

I know that a countable intersection of closed sets or countable union of closed sets is Souslin set. I want to find an example of set which is not Souslin set. First, I assume that $A=[0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not Souslin set, but $A$ is $F_\sigma.$ Then, my assumption is not true. How to construct a set which is not Souslin set? Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Every Borel set is Suslin. And consistently, every set of reals is Borel. So you need to rely on the axiom of choice here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe that "every Borel set is Suslin" depends on having codes for Borel sets, while "every set  of reals is Borel" depends on *not* requiring Borel sets to have codes. So I don't think you can combine the two, because they use different definitions of "Borel". In fact, with the OP's definition of "Suslin set", it seems there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ Suslin sets, so some set of reals is not Suslin. (Probably, the set of codes of well-orderings will be an example in ZF, just as in the presence of AC.)

Comment: In my previous comment, "at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ wasn't good wording. What I should have said is that the continuum can be mapped onto the collection of all Suslin sets, so that collection can't be the whole power set of the continuum.

Comment: To clarify Asaf's comment for the OP: it is consistent *with ZF* that every set of reals is Borel. In ZFC - even with a small amount of choice - this is of course false. Moreover, there are simple examples (e.g. the set of reals coding well-orderings), so this isn't a case of choice letting you construct pathological sets but rather giving you the right tools to analyze the sets you already have. Reflecting this, there is a notion of "coded Borel set" which behaves much better in ZF, and indeed ZF alone proves that there are non-coded Borel sets. And Andreas' comment gets at the subtlety here.

Comment: @Andreas: Good point.

Answer (score 8):

You can find a proof of this in Kechris' [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749), Theorem 14.2 in combination with Theorem 25.7.

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ construed as the topological product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology. Theorem 25.7 shows that a subset of $\mathcal{N}$ is Souslin if and only if it is **analytic**, i.e., the continuous image of a separable completely metrizable space.

Now Theorem 14.2 states that there exists an analytic set $A\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ that is not Borel. In the course of the proof, it is shown that $\mathcal{N}\setminus A$ is not analytic, so this is a very sharp example: a non analytic set with analytic complement.

In any case, the cardinality argument by Andreas Blass [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561150/an-example-of-set-which-is-not-souslin-set#comment5302584_2561150) is extremely simple: Each analytic subset of $\mathcal{N}$ is determined by a countable family of closed sets. Since there are exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$ of the latter, you have $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} =2^{\aleph_0}$ analytic subsets of $\mathcal{N}$, hence there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ non analytic subsets.

Both arguments go through for every separable completely metrizable uncountable space.

Comment: You probably should indicate why all Suslin sets are analytic.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh, thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @MaurtenErik Thank you for the reward!